# make loop to create list of igraph objects in R

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I'd like to create a list of Igraph objects with the data used for each Igraph object determined by another variable.

This is how I create a single Igraph object

```
netEdges <- NULL

for (idi in c("nom1", "nom2", "nom3")) {
        netEdge <- net[c("id", idi)]
        names(netEdge) <- c("id", "friendID")
        netEdge$weight <- 1
        netEdges <- rbind(netEdges, netEdge)
    }

g <- graph.data.frame(netEdges, directed=TRUE)
```

For each unique value of `net$community` I'd like to make a new Igraph object.  Then I would like to calculate measures of centrality for each object and then bring those measures back into my `net` dataset.  Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please expand on your question? Providing a sample of data will help people to answer your question. You can use dput() for your dataset or create a small dummy set for trialling the code. Also, unless I'm missing something, I don't see where 'net$community' is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code you provide isn't completely reproducible, what follows is not guaranteed to run. It is intended as a guide for how to structure a real solution. If you provide example data that others can use to run your code, you will get better answers.

The simplest way to do this is probably to split `net` into a list with one element for each unique value of `community` and then apply your graph building code to each piece, storing the results for each piece in another list. There are several ways to doing this type of thing in R, one of which is to use `lapply`:

```
#Break net into pieces based on unique values of community
netSplit <- split(net,net$community)

#Define a function to apply to each element of netSplit
myFun <- function(dataPiece){
    netEdges <- NULL

    for (idi in c("nom1", "nom2", "nom3")) {
        netEdge <- dataPiece[c("id", idi)]
        names(netEdge) <- c("id", "friendID")
        netEdge$weight <- 1
        netEdges <- rbind(netEdges, netEdge)
    }

    g <- graph.data.frame(netEdges, directed=TRUE)
    #This will return the graph itself; you could change the function
    # to return other values calculated on the graph
    g
}

#Apply your function to each subset (piece) of your data:
result <- lapply(netSplit,FUN = myFun)
```

If all has gone well, `result` should be a list containing a graph (or whatever you modified `myFun` to return) for each unique value of `community`. Other popular tools for doing similar tasks include `ddply` from the `plyr` package.